# Permission denied on everywhere

Tags: raspbian, permissions, failure

I am using debian os on pi3 and I completely lost the control of device. I messed up when I try to chmod on some folder. Here is what I did. I was already at: /var/www/html so i wanted to chmod the contents of html and executed that command:

```
sudo chmod o=rwx /.
```

After that I cant even change directory, I cant use sudo commands too. If there is a way to restore my pi it would be perfect. thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: I believe that certain Linux distributions will allow you to read off the Pi's sd card which would allow you to recover some of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinstall, and restore any changes from your backups.

Comment: One could add: "you sure do have backups, don't you?"

Comment: @Ghanima i can relate

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the sd card with all the data on a computer, and restore and necessary files after reinstalling.